# How to add a value of a element in one XML as attribute in another xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT working on XML to XML transformation. I want to add a value of a element in one XML as attribute in another xml using XSLT.
The structure looks like this.

Source XML:

```
 <content>
          <aaa>value</aaa>
 </content>
```

Target XML:

```
 <block>
         <ele name="value"></ele>
 <block>
```

I am unable to do this.Please Help.

Comment: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200110/post40030.html

Comment: http://old.nabble.com/Dynamically-load-XML-within-XSLT-to8143261.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="block">
            <xsl:element name="ele">
                <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="/content/aaa"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: its working???? where are you loading **another XML document** ?! You are just accessing another **node** from the **same XML**